# Effects of not freeing memory in a Windows application?

Tags: windows, memory, memory-leaks

I have an MFC C++ application that usually runs constantly in the system tray.

It allocates a very extensive tree of objects in memory, which causes the application to take several seconds to free, when the application needs to shutdown.

All my objects are allocated using `new` and typically freed using `delete`.

If I just skip deleting all the objects, in order to quit faster, what are the effects if any?

Does Windows realize the process is dead and reclaims the memory automatically?

I know that not freeing allocated memory is almost sacrilegious, but thought I would ask to see what everyone else thinks.

The application only shuts down when either the users system shuts down, or if they choose to shut the program down themselves.

Comment: Not releasing memory ensures that, whenever you have a *real* leak, you'll never be able to diagnose it.  Don't skip it in the Debug build.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When a process terminates the system will reclaim all resources. This includes releasing open handles to kernel objects and allocated memory. If you do not free memory during process termination it has no adverse effect on the operating system.

You will find substantial information about the steps performed during process termination at [Terminating a process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686722.aspx). With respect to your question the following is the relevant section:

> Terminating a process has the following results:
>
> ...
>
> Any resources allocated by the process are freed.

You probably should not skip the cleanup step in your debug builds though. Otherwise you will not get memory leak diagnostics for real memory leaks.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, and the tip about testing the debug version.